# Is there a Mid-Atlantic pronouncing dictionary?

Tags: reference-request, pronunciation, resource-request, dialects, american-english

I’m someone who speaks what I would describe as “a conservative American accent”. I sound like General American from a couple decades ago. I distinguish between the vowels in Mary, marry, and merry, as well as baht, bot, and bought. If the Mid-Atlantic Accent makes a distinction, chances are I do too.

However, every American English pronunciation dictionary I can find doesn’t also make these distinctions, so they’re useless to me.

**Is there an American English pronouncing dictionary online that preserves the distinction between father–bother, cot–caught, and Mary–marry–merry?**

I’ll show what I’ve found so far and where they fail to meet my use case. The tests are:

1. It should *not* have a Mary–marry–merry merger, but instead distinguish between all three.
2. It should *not* have a father–bother or cot–caught merger.
3. It should pronounce words like “bath”, “tomato”, and “vitamin” the American way (/bæθ/ /təˈmeɪtoʊ/ /ˈvaɪtəmɪn/) instead of the British way (/bɑːθ/ /təmɑːtəʊ/ /ˈvɪtəmɪn/).

## Carnegie-Mellon University

MARRY **M EH1 R IY0**
MARY **M EH1 R IY0**
MERRY **M EH1 R IY0**
❌ *Fail — 3-way merger*

BAHT **B AA1 T**
BOT (not found)
↪*NOT **N AA1 T***
BOUGHT **B AA1 T**
❌ *Fail — 3-way merger*

## AmEPD v0.2

MARRY **M EH1 R IY0**
MARY **M EH1 R IY0**
MERRY **M EH1 R IY0**
❌ *Fail — 3-way merger*

BAHT  B AA1 T
BOT  **B AO1 T**
BOUGHT  **B AO1 T**
❌ *Fail — cot–caught merger*

## Merriam-Webster Dictionary

marry **ˈmer-ē, ˈma-rē**
Mary **ˈmer-ē, ˈma-rē, ˈmā-rē**
mer​ry **ˈmer-ē, ˈme-rē**
❌ *Fail — 3-way merger*

baht **ˈbät**
bot **ˈbät**
bought ˈbȯt
❌ *Fail — father–bother merger*

## Read Lexicon

The only one without either merger that I could find was the Read Lexicon, a word list for the Shavian alphabet, which is a writing system that distinguishes between all those and then some, but it defaults to British pronunciations in words like “tomato” and “vitamin”.

marry  ˈmæri
mary  ˈmeəri
merry  ˈmeri
✅ *Pass*

baht (only found as “bt”)
↪bt  bɑːt
bot  bɒt
bought  bɔːt
✅ *Pass*

bath  bÆθ
bath  bⱭːθ
✅ *Trap–bath split is easily filterable due to its use of uppercase IPA letters*

tomato  **təˈmɑːtəʊ (only)**
vitamin  **ˈvɪtəmɪn (only)**
❌ *Other words are British-only*

Comment: I vote for reopening this question: The request for a specialised ressource is perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: In typical/traditional Mid-Atlantic accent, BATH is either PALM/START or an intermediate sound near [äː], not TRAP.

Comment: Does "mid-Atlantic" here mean "like they talk in Philadelphia and Baltimore" or "like early-twentieth-century film actors talked"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *American Heritage Dictionary* has:

- *Mary*: mâr′ē
- *marry*: măr′ē
- *merry*: mĕr′ē
- *baht*: bät
- *bot*: bŏt
- *bought*: bôt
- *bath*: băth, bäth
- *tomato*: tə-mā′tō, -mä′-
- *vitamin*: vī′tə-mĭn

Answer (score 3):

Kenyon and Knott's *Pronouncing dictionary* preserves distinctions, but doesn't label them. It gives 4 transcriptions of "Mary" (mɛrɪ, mɛ:rɪ, merɪ, mærɪ), one for "marry" (mærɪ} and one for "merry" (mɛrɪ). It does not list "baht" but does distinguish "bot" (bɑt) from "bought" (bɔt), though doesn't indicate that merger exists in some dialects (meaning that it is not a complete listing of all pronunciations, relevant to understanding their 4 variants of "Mary" and their 1 variant of "merry, marry").

The problem with "Mid Atlantic Accent" is that it's an extinct theatrical dialect, but there is a book "Speak with distinction" which probably provides the standards set by the author (Edith Skinner).

Comment: K&K is online at https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater